# Regular expression for a number with fractional and decimal part

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I am new to regular expression , i want a regular expression which satisfies following reqs:
User can enter a value in which the fractional part should not be more than 3 digits ,it can be less than 3 digits and the decimal part should not more than 1 digit.The number can be without decimal part in that case the digits should not more than 3.It is also possible to just have decimal part.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this,

```
^\d{0,3}(\.(?=\d)\d){0,1}$
```

This matches the followings,

123
1.2
12.3
123.4

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot !! i have modified the expression to suit my need of taking into consideration of either + or - sign. i have used the following expression : ^(\-?|\+?)\d{0,3}(\.(?=\d)\d){0,1}$. But am getting a crash when my using this line of code :           static const boost::regex ex( "^(\-?|\+?)\d{0,3}(\.(?=\d)\d){0,1}$" );    Is it because of an exception ? please guide me

Comment: Well, if you need to include the + and - signs, I would use the original expresion above as follows,

^[\-|\+]\d{0,3}(\.(?=\d)\d){0,1}$

However, this might not be the reason for carsh. Appriciate if you vote for the answer.

Comment: thank you !! one last request...in the above given answer by you i want 1. , 12. , 123. conditions to be satisfied too.....i have been looking but no clear solution .It allows me to use .1 but not 1. etc .

Comment: I tried something like this "^\d{0,3}\.?(?<=\.)\d{0,1}$"  but its failing for 1 , 12 , 123 . Please Help